# Word/phrase for habit of replying only when pressed

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word (or phrase) that describes the action of responding to requests only when someone presses you about them?

For example, let's say I ask John to get me a quote for a product, and he says he'll get back to me. After several days with no word, I call John and ask him what happened with the quote I was waiting for. He replies, "I was just about to call you! Here is the info..." It is clear that John had the information much earlier, but he didn't send it to me until I asked for it (either intentionally or because he forgot). I would like to describe this situation with an utterance like: *"I asked John about that quote I was waiting for, and he ____ to me with the info."*

The word I'm looking for essentially means "respond", but it carries this extra connotation of a rapid response driven by already having the requested information. 
I feel like it could be something like "snapped back" (which carries the sense of spontaneity, but not the existing-information aspect, and it has the extra unneeded connotatuon of responding angrily).

A OneLook search supplied me with ["jump"](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=respond%20quickly%20with%20information), but that's not the right word either - "he jumped back with the info" doesn't quite carry the intended meaning.

Comment: See these words and related phrases to see if one of them sounds right: accede, relent, divulge

Comment: The word "reverted" could be used. Or you could even say "swiftly/briskly responded/replied"

Comment: @Scripter1000 Thanks, but none of those is quite what I'm looking for. It's not so much the "revealing" of information that is important so much as the seeming spontaneity of the reveal.

Comment: @Apoorva I'm not sure that *revert* can be used regarding speech. And all of the variants on "replied quickly" are technically correct but don't have the right connotation.

Comment: @KannE Actually, *spouted off* does evoke the sort of sense I want! That might be the closest thing to an answer I can find; if you make it an answer I'll choose it. And thanks for the welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

> I asked john about the  quote I was waiting for, and  he revealed the information to me.

The  answer  is  not  possible  without changing the structure  of  the given sentence.

But *reveal* means  to  give  the  hidden or known information when needed or  forced  to inform.

Even  the  verbs *divulge*  or  *disclose*  may  serve your  purpose.

Here is link

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reveal

Comment: Thanks, but reveal isn't quite right. Although you're right that changing the structure of the sentence may be necessary, because I don't know for sure that I'm looking for a single verb or a phrasal colloquialism.